# When to use which ASCII representation

Tags: html, ascii

Doing web work with PHP, JavaScript, HTML, etc.  Had an issue where using a special character, in this case the less than symbol, had to be replaced with an ASCII representation in order for the code to work properly.  No issues with the concept but how do you decide on which ASCII representation to use?  Stated another way, are there some guidelines on when to use Dec 60, HEX \x3c, Octal \074, or just the HTML special character &#60?

Answer (score 1):

They are all the same character and should all be interpreted the same by a browser.

If possible, use the actual character literal, though in HTML `<` has a special meaning and should be escaped as `&lt;`.

Comment: Oded,  Thanks for the nearly instant answer.  To be clear are you saying 1. in this case use "<" if possible, that being the character literal and 2.  if not possible you may use any of the other options, in this case Dec 60, Hex \x3c, Octal \074, HTML number &#60 or &lt and that for all browsers the issues with the special meaning, in this case a closing tag will be escaped?

Comment: to avoid strange behaviour you should ALWAYS quote symbols with special meanings (in HTML <, > and & ) and non-ascii-symbols ( like ä: &auml; ), in case you are not using a default encoding in your html or http header.